# How do massless particles have the same chirality and helicity when they are different properties?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, electroweak, chirality, helicity

I read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#:%7E:text=A%20chiral%20phenomenon%20is%20one,is%20the%20same%20as%20chirality.) about chirality and helicity.  At some point it says

> For massless particles, chirality is the same as helicity.

But as far as I know, helicity takes form in numbers, $(-1/2, +1/2)$, while chirality takes form in left or right (left chiral, right chiral). So how do these two different properties become the same?

Comment: For massless particles, the eigenstates of helicity are ***also*** those of the two chirality projection operators. The "how" is explained in QFT texts describing Dirac spinors. Are you comfortable with those solutions of the Dirac equation?

Comment: I think the Wikipedia article means that for massless particles the chirality and helicity are always left, left or right, right and not that the chirality and helicity eigenvalues are the same.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232591/50583

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure this is what you want, but, for massless particles, so the 3-momentum cannot vanish, you can define, in any frame, $\hat p\equiv  \vec p /|\vec p|$; hence, you [have](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394236/spin-operator-in-terms-of-gamma-5)
$$
h=\hat p \cdot \vec S= \frac{1}{2} \gamma^0 \gamma^5 \vec \gamma \cdot \hat p.
$$
But this manifestly commutes with chirality, $\gamma^5$, so the two operators share eigenvectors.

***Left-chiral ones have negative helicity, and right-chiral ones positive helicity.*** The numerical magnitude of eigenvalues  is irrelevant here: The article focusses on the *sign* of the helicity.

For more details of how Dirac equation spinors realize the above for both particles and antiparticles, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687530/how-do-we-show-that-for-massless-fermions-helcity-and-chirality-align?rq=1). Note how a fermion reverses chirality, spin and helicity upon charge conjugation.